# Should I close an issue after merging on develop or master? What about marking it as done in a board?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm looking for best practices on how to deal with issues, boards and merge requests on Gitlab.

[This is my board on Gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdaTg.jpg)

The merge request linked to issue #3 (with label "Doing") was merged on the develop branch (I'm following [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)). I'd like to mark this issue as done because we're finished working on it, however it's not merged on master yet. Should I close the issue? If not, is there a convention on how I can mark it as "done" in the sense that we're finished our work on it?

Comment: On a bit of a side note, I've heard a lot of people have issues following gitflow when using GitLab because it wasn't built for that, but instead was built for the [GitLab flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html). If you want to use gitflow, I recommend using labels to mark states as a "workaround"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When to close an issue is not only related to the particular branching model, but to your work item management process, i.e what is your **definition of done**?

**In [gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you only merge to master on production deployments**, whether you consider issues done before then is a matter of taste, but in case you are working in an agile fashoin a common definition of done would be that the feature is implemented, documented, reviewed and tested, in other words ready to be deployed to your production environment (but not necessarily deployed there yet).

**To visualize such a workflow better** you may benefit from introducing a few more columns in your board, like "TEST/QA" and "Review" to indicate that an issue has moved from implementation to review and later to QA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a follow-up: how would I name the board column where you reviewed and tested an issue (merged it to develop) but you're waiting for other issues to be done in order to merge it to master? So like a change to the code is ready, but it has to wait for the other changes in the same release to be completed to be merged to master.

Comment: Either you consider the issue done once it is tested and "ready" for production, or you introduce a state called "Ready for production" where you put issues where you expect no further work besides deploying them to production. Which startegy to choose ones again comes back to your definition of done for an issue is.